# how to open ms files of google drive in my app

Tags: google-drive-api, xcode4.6

I am using xcode 4.6. i used google drive api for open,edit,new docs operation on google drive.but i don't know how to open ms files in my app.i used mime type but it's not working properly.and if possible please give me an example.